# Get Dataset returned by Remote in Twitter Typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, tags, typeahead.js

I have created a Typeahead Autocomplete box and am tying it together with tagmanager.js. Everything works, except making sure that the chosen tag is one of the provided choices from the typeahead suggestion list.

```
self.tagApi = $("#itemTag").tagsManager({
  onlyTagList: true,  //This option is unimplemented in TagsManager 3.0
  maxTags: 1
});

self.tAhead = $("#itemTag").typeahead({
  name: 'items',
  limit: 15,
  remote: {
    url: '/api/get_items_for_typeahead/%QUERY'
  }
}).on('typeahead:selected', function(e, data, data_set_name) {

  //I want to check that it is a valid suggestion here

  $("#itemTag").tagsManager("pushTag", data.value);

});
```

Anyone know how to get the returned dataset?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `filter` to your `remote`. In it, simply save the datums and then use later in your `selected` event handler. Like this:

```
$itemTag = $('#itemTag');

self.tagApi = $itemTag.tagsManager({
    onlyTagList: true,  // This option is unimplemented in TagsManager 3.0
    maxTags: 1,
});

var lastTypeaheadResponse = null;

self.tAhead = $itemTag.typeahead({
    name: 'items',
    limit: 15,
    remote: {
        url: '/api/get_items_for_typeahead/%QUERY',
        filter: function (response) {
            lastTypeaheadResponse = response;
            return response;
        },
    },
}).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, data, dataSetName) {
    // iterate over lastTypeaheadResponse and check what you want to check
    $itemTag.tagsManager('pushTag', data.value);
});
```